# Changing Integral Bounds

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals

[I'm studying for Exam P and I was wondering what the need to change the lower limit of this integral was.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwxYS.png)

> Substituting $u=1+x$, $du=dx$,
>   $$
>    \int_0^\infty\frac{3x}{(1+x)^4}\;dx
>    = \int_1^\infty\frac{3(u-1)}{u^4}\;du
>    = 3\int_1^\infty(u^{-3}-u^{-4})\;du
>    = 3\left[\frac{u^{-2}}{-2}-\frac{u^{-3}}{-3}\right]_1^\infty
>    = 3\left[\frac12-\frac13\right]
>    = 3/2-1
>    = \frac12
> $$

Answer (score 3):

The original integral has $x$ ranging from $0$ to $\infty$. After the substitution these need to be translated to bounds for $u$. Since $u=1+x$, the lower bound $x=0$ corresponds to $u=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in [0;\infty)$, then $x+1\in [1;\infty)$

So by substitution: $u\in[1;\infty)$

Hence: $$\int_0^\infty g(x+1)\operatorname d x = \int_1^\infty g(u)\operatorname d u$$

$\blacksquare$